# Import Font from Dropbox

Tags: css, import, fonts, font-face

I am trying to use fonts hosted in drobox.

It seems that all fonts are stored in Dropbox in a zip as you can see bellow
[image]

My question is : Is it possible to import in an HTML page fonts hosted like that? and if it is possible how?

I tried using @font-face and  @import without success

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Web Font Sample</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            @font-face {
            font-family: 'Cera-Pro-Medium';
                src:  url('https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g5xuhd#####x69r8/AAD#######EOa'),
            }
            
            .classname {
                font-family: 'Cera-Pro-Medium';
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="classname">
            test
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```